# Index was outside the bounds of the array - VB

Tags: vb.net

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim a As Integer
    Dim b As Integer
    Dim c As Integer
    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        If CheckBox1.Checked = True Then
            a += 1
        Else : a += 0
        End If
        If CheckBox2.Checked = True Then
            b += 1
        Else : b += 0
        End If
        If CheckBox3.Checked = True Then
            c += 1
        Else : c += 0
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Dim max As Integer = 0
        Dim d() As Integer = {a, b, c}
        Dim f() As String = {"ch1", "ch2", "ch3"}
        For i As Integer = 0 To 2
            If max < d(i) Then
                max = d(i)
            Else : max = max
            End If
        Next
        Label1.Text = f(max)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: What's the question? Which line is causing the problem?

Comment: `Dim d() As Integer = {a, b, c}`? Integer? Really? And then, `max < d(i)`?

Comment: when I press the button2,vb say "Index was outside the bounds of the array - VB"

Comment: Label1.Text = f(max) is the problem

Comment: Doesn't answer the question, but the `Else` sections of the `If` statements in Button1_Click are all completely superfluous.  If the box isn't checked then add 0 to the number?  Might as well just not have those lines at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, in summary you're using checkboxes to increment numbers every time `Button1` is clicked.  These values are stored in variables `a`, `b` and `c`, which when `Button2` is clicked, are put into an integer array.  From the looks of your code you're then trying to find which one of these is the largest value and display a value from another array based off that index.  The problem, of course, is that you're taking the *value* of `d` and using it as the *index* of `f`.  The value of `max` then becomes an arbitrarily large number, easily exceeding the bounds of `f` which in your example only has three values in it.  You might want to try it more like this:

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim max As Integer = 0
    Dim index as Integer = 0
    Dim d() As Integer = {a, b, c}
    Dim f() As String = {"ch1", "ch2", "ch3"}
    For i As Integer = 0 To 2
        If max < d(i) Then
            max = d(i)
            index = i
        Else : max = max
        End If
    Next
    Label1.Text = f(index)
End Sub
```

This still uses `max` as the comparer, but takes note of the index of the `For` loop when it reaches a new highest number, using that to pull out the value of `f`, ensuring that the value of `index` is never higher than `i`.

Answer (score 0):

The values of a,b and c are being incremented ever time you click the first button depending on their checked state.  Then when you loop thru and get the max of the variables you are trying to use that as an indec into the f() array.  The f() array can only go from 0 to 2 but max can be any value.  You cannot use max to select from the array.  What are you trying to do ?